# How to solve undefined method `permit' for :user:Symbol error in ror-4

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Please help me to solve this error.When update action is executing this error is showing.

**Error:**

```
NoMethodError in UsersController#update
undefined method `permit' for :user:Symbol
```

My code snippets are given below.

**views/users/edit.html.erb**

```
<h1>Edit your data</h1>
<%= form_for @user,:url => {:action => 'update',:id => params[:id]} do |f| %>
    <% if @user.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">
          <h2><%= pluralize(@user.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
            <% @user.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
                <li><%= message %></li>
            <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.text_field:name,:value => @edit.name %>
    <%= f.email_field:email,:value => @edit.email %>
    <%= f.text_field:message,:value => @edit.message %>
    <%= f.submit "Update" %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to "Back",users_index_path %>
```

**controller/users_controller.rb**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def index

  end
  def new
    @user=User.new
  end
  def create
    @user=User.new(users_params)
    if @user.save
      flash[:notice]="Your data is saved succesfully"
      flash[:color]="valid"
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
    else
      flash[:alert]="You are entering wrong data"
      flash[:color]="invalid"
      render :new
    end
  end
  def show
    @user=User.all
  end
  def delete
   @user=User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.delete
      flash[:notice]=@user.name+"has deleted successfully"
      flash[:color]="valid"
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
    else
      flash[:alert]=@user.name+"could not delete.Please check it.."
      flash[:color]="invalid"
      render :show
    end
  end
  def edit
    @edit=User.find(params[:id])
    @user=User.new
  end
  def update
    @user=User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(update_params)
      flash[:notice]="Your data has updated successfully"
      flash[:color]="valid"
      redirect_to :action => 'index'
    else
      flash[:alert]="Your data could not update..check it.."
      flash[:color]="invalid"
      render :edit

    end
  end
  private
  def users_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :message,pets_attributes: [:name, :email,:message])
  end
  def update_params
    params.require (:user).permit(:name,:email,:message,pets_attributes: [:name, :email,:message])
  end
end
```

**model/user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pets
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pets
  EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\z/i
  validates :name,  :presence => true,:length => { :minimum => 5 }
  validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :format => EMAIL_REGEX
  validates :message,  :presence => true
end
```

Please help me to solve the above error.

Comment: You have asked many questions the last few weeks, but you haven't accepted even a single answer yet. To be part of the StackOverflow community, you need to up vote good answers, and accept the answers to your question that helps you the most (if any). Please read through the help center for more information about this.

Answer (score 2):

You have space between `require` and `(:user)`. Your current code is equivalent to:

```
def update_params
  params.require(:user.permit(:name,:email,:message,pets_attributes: [:name, :email,:message]))
end
```

As you can see now, you call `permit` method on `:user` symbol and this is direct cause of error.

It should be:

```
  def update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:name,:email,:message,pets_attributes: [:name, :email,:message])
  end
```

BTW having two methods that do exactly same thing is quite pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Check your question:

```
you have a space after require and before (:user)
```

Try:

```
 def update_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:name,:email,:message,
     pets_attributes: [:name, :email,:message])
  end
```

For a better way, you can have just one method:

```
def user_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:name,:email,:message,
     pets_attributes: [:name, :email,:message])
end
```

Instead of having separate filter methods for new and edit, you can have just one method and reuse that in both new and edit.

Just keep things Simply DRY.